# how to export HDF5 file to NumPy using H5PY?

Tags: python, numpy, hdf5, h5py

I have an existing hdf5 file with three arrays, i want to extract one of the arrays using h5py.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

`h5py` already reads files in as numpy arrays, so just:

```
with h5py.File('the_filename', 'r') as f:
    my_array = f['array_name'][()]
```

The `[()]` means to read the entire array in; if you don't do that, it doesn't read the whole data but instead gives you lazy access to sub-parts (very useful when the array is huge but you only need a small part of it).

Comment: Thanks a lot Dougal.I have modified the code to:                     >>> f = h5py.File('D:/!JODI/Macau Wind/u_100m/20100101.hdf5', 'r')
my_array = f['u'].value
f.close()    

Another stupid question is the out putarray is in a file? where can i find the output array? thank you so much

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by the output array: `my_array` from above? Any changes you make to that are only stored in memory unless you save them yourself (into an `h5py.File` or with something like `numpy.save`).

Comment: For posterity: the `.value` method no longer works. Use `f['array_name'][()]` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For this question it is way overkill but if you have a lot of things like this to do I use a package [SpacePy](http://spacepy.lanl.gov/doc/index.html) that makes some of this easier.

[datamodel.fromHDF5()](http://spacepy.lanl.gov/doc/autosummary/spacepy.datamodel.fromHDF5.html#spacepy.datamodel.fromHDF5) documentation This returns a dictionary of arrays stored in a similar way to how h5py handles data.